# Has anyone seen this error while running TestComplete?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, testcomplete

I have been having problems working with TestComplete. What I have are:

- TestComplete Version 10.0.531.7, 64 bits
- Windows 7 Enterprise, Service Pack 1

Whenever I start TestComplete, it gives me this error. Please see screenshot below:

[image]

If I choose to

- Don't terminate the application AND
- Don't send

TestComplete allows me to proceed but after I click on "Edit" button then "Next", it tells me that **the specified data source** can not be found. Please see screenshot below:

[image]

I am not really sure if those two errors are related, has anyone seen this kind of error before?

PS. I have tried reinstalling Oracle data base 11.2.0, but it does not help.

Many thanks

Comment: You are using an extremely old version of TestComplete. Have you tried installing TestComplete 11.20 or at least TestComplete 10.60?

Comment: You should [contact vendor support](http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete). This is not a programming question, so it's offtopic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

- I needed to install Oracle `ODAC101040.exe`

Now the problem has been solved.